# Hyperparameter Tuning in Random forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I was trying Random Forest Algorithm on [Boston](https://www.kaggle.com/c/boston-housing) dataset to predict the house prices `medv` with the help of sklearn's [`RandomForestRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).In all I tried `3 iterations` as below

**Iteration 1**: Using the model with default hyperparameters

```
#1. import the class/model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
#2. Instantiate the estimator
RFReg = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1, n_jobs = -1) 
#3. Fit the model with data aka model training
RFReg.fit(X_train, y_train)

#4. Predict the response for a new observation
y_pred = RFReg.predict(X_test)


y_pred_train = RFReg.predict(X_train)
```

**Results of Iteration 1**

```
{'RMSE Test': 2.9850839211419435, 'RMSE Train': 1.2291604936401441}
```

**Iteration 2**: I used [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) to get optimum values of hyper-parameters

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
RFReg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 500, random_state = 1, n_jobs = -1) 

param_grid = { 
    'max_features' : ["auto", "sqrt", "log2"],
    'min_samples_split' : np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10),
     'max_depth' : [x for x in range(1,20)]


from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
CV_rfc = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=RFReg, param_distributions =param_grid, n_jobs = -1, cv= 10, n_iter = 50)
CV_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

So I got the *best* hyperparameters as follows

```
CV_rfc.best_params_
#{'min_samples_split': 0.1, 'max_features': 'auto', 'max_depth': 18}
CV_rfc.best_score_
#0.8021713812777814
```

So I trained a new model with *best* hyperparameters as below

```
#1. import the class/model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
#2. Instantiate the estimator
RFReg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 500, random_state = 1, n_jobs = -1, min_samples_split = 0.1, max_features = 'auto', max_depth = 18) 
#3. Fit the model with data aka model training
RFReg.fit(X_train, y_train)

#4. Predict the response for a new observation
y_pred = RFReg.predict(X_test)


y_pred_train = RFReg.predict(X_train)
```

**Results of Iteration 2**

```
{'RMSE Test': 3.2836794902147926, 'RMSE Train': 2.71230367772569}
```

**Iteration 3**: I use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to get optimum values of hyper-parameters

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
RFReg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 500, random_state = 1, n_jobs = -1) 

param_grid = { 
    'max_features' : ["auto", "sqrt", "log2"],
    'min_samples_split' : np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10),
     'max_depth' : [x for x in range(1,20)]

}

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=RFReg, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 10, n_jobs = -1)
CV_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

So I got the *best* hyperparameters as follows

```
CV_rfc.best_params_
#{'max_depth': 12, 'max_features': 'auto', 'min_samples_split': 0.1}
CV_rfc.best_score_
#0.8021820114800677
```

**Results of Iteration 3**

```
{'RMSE Test': 3.283690568225705, 'RMSE Train': 2.712331014201783}
```

My Function to evaluate `RMSE`

```
def model_evaluate(y_train, y_test, y_pred, y_pred_train):
    metrics = {}
    #RMSE Test
    rmse_test = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
    #RMSE Train
    rmse_train = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred_train))

    metrics = {
              'RMSE Test': rmse_test,
              'RMSE Train': rmse_train}

    return metrics
```

So I had below questions after 3 iterations

1. Why are the results of *tuned* model worst than the model with default parameters even when I am using `RandomSearchCV` and `GridSearchCV`. Ideally the model should give good results when tuned with cross-validation
2. I know that cross-validation will take place only for the combination  of values present in `param_grid`.There could be values which are *good* but not included in my `param_grid`. So how do I deal with this kind of situation
3. How do I decide what *range* of values I should try for `max_features`, `min_samples_split`, `max_depth` or for that matter any hyper-parameters in a machine learning model to increase its accuracy.(So that I can at least get a better tuned model than the model with default hyper-parameters)

Comment: There are not "hard" scientific answers (or even broad guidelines) for your questions #2 & #3; this is part of the art, coming from experience (you have arguably gained some yourself, which might translate in practice "always try the default parameters, too"); and probably a possible answer to your question #1 may lie in your question #2...

Answer (score 3):

> Why are the results of tuned model worst than the model with default
>   parameters even when I am using RandomSearchCV and GridSearchCV.
>   Ideally the model should give good results when tuned with
>   cross-validation

Your second question kind of answers your first one, but I tried to reproduce your results on the boston dataset, I got `{'test_rmse':3.987, 'train_rmse':1.442}` with default parameters, `{'test_rmse':3.98, 'train_rmse':3.426}` for 'tuned' parameters with random search and `{'test_rmse':3.993, 'train_rmse':3.481}` with grid search. Then I used `hyperopt` with following parameter space

```
 {'max_depth': hp.choice('max_depth', range(1, 100)),
    'max_features': hp.choice('max_features', range(1, x_train.shape[1])),
    'min_samples_split': hp.uniform('min_samples_split', 0.1, 1)}
```

After about 200 runs results looked like this,
[image]
so I widened the space to `'min_samples_split', 0.01, 1` which got me the best result of `{'test_rmse':3.278, 'train_rmse':1.716}` with `min_samples_split` equal to 0.01. According to documentation the formula for `min_samples_split` is `ceil(min_samples_split * n_samples)` which in our case gives `np.ceil(0.1 * len(x_train))`=34 which could be kind of big for a small dataset like this.

> I know that cross-validation will take place only for the combination
>   of values present in param_grid.There could be values which are good
>   but not included in my param_grid. So how do I deal with this kind of
>   situation
>
> How do I decide what range of values I should try for
>   max_features, min_samples_split, max_depth or for that matter any
>   hyper-parameters in a machine learning model to increase its
>   accuracy.(So that I can atleast get a better tuned model than the
>   model with default hyper-parameters)

You can't know this in advance, so you have to do research for each algorithm to see what kind of parameter spaces are usually searched (good source for this is kaggle, e.g. google `kaggle kernel random forest`), merge them, account for your dataset features and optimize over them using some kind of [Bayesian Optimization](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2017/slides/lec21.pdf) algorithm (there are [multiple existing libraries](http://ash-aldujaili.github.io/blog/2018/04/01/coco-bayesopt/) for this) which try to optimally select for a new parameter value to choose.

Comment: Neat demonstration of how `min_samples_split` can be a more useful (consistent) hyperparameter to limit depth than `max_depth`. I guess `min_samples_leaf` would look similar?

Comment: @jonnor Yeah, `min_samples_leaf`graph looked very similar.